# Deletar arquivo de imagem ao excluir do editor tinymce

Tags: php, tinymce

Estou usando **Tinymce**, para editar os textos do site e também fazer o upload de imagens.

O upload e seu aparecimento esta funcionando perfeitamente.

[image: Editor]

### Questão

É possível enviar algum comando GET com o nome da imagem para que possa também ser apagada no diretório?

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  directionality: 'pt_BR',
  language: 'pt_BR',
  height: 400,
  menubar: true,
  plugins: [
    " advlist anchor autolink codesample image imagetools",
    " lists link media noneditable preview",
    " searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount paste code fullscreen"
  ],
  toolbar: "undo redo | bold underline italic | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | image paste | code | fullscreen",
  paste_as_text: true,
  paste_data_images: true,
  entity_encoding: "raw",
  images_upload_url: './upload_tinymce.php'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi (a pergunta está confusa) você quer deletar uma imagem do servidor que esteja embarcada dentro do tinymce acaso o usuário remova ela da área de edição?

Eu devo dizer que isso é uma má ideia, isto porque estes tipos de editores suportam Ctrl+Z, então se deletar no momento que remover a imagem da área de edição e o usuário resolver fazer um Ctrl+Z ele não terá mais a imagem do servidor, pode ser até que ela esteja em cache no navegador, mas do lado do servidor ela não existirá.

A solução que proponho é simplesmente resolver isto no back-end no momento que você salva os dados no servidor, é basicamente simples, ao enviar o conteúdo do tinymce para o servidor você poderá usar o o `DomDocument` do PHP para fazer o parse em HTML, mas isso só vai funcionar se este editor for para uma **unica coisa**, se não for o caso então o que você deve fazer é checar todas edições que usuários fizeram, supondo que você tenha uma tabela com algo como (vamos chamar de tabela "postagens"):

| id | titulo | conteudo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | titulo 1 | `foo bar <img src="baz.jpg"> um` |
| 2 | titulo 2 | `lorem y <img src="bar.jpg"> dois` |

Então na **hora de salvar** você pode checar todas "postagens" e obter todas imagens (tudo isto é hipotético) e fazendo o parse DOM disto tudo para pegar todas imagens (segue pseudocódigo para entendimento, independente de PDO ou mysqli ou outros bancos):

```
if (!query('INSERT INTO postagens')) // OU UPDATE, depende de como você preparou a lógica
{
     die('Falhou ao salvar');
}

function pegar_imagens($doc)
{
     $imagens = array();

     forach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
     {
          $path = $img->getAttribute('src');

          if (!$path) continue;

          $imagens[] = basename($path);
     }

     return $imagens;
}

$todas_imagens = array();

$data = query('SELECT conteudo FROM postagens');

while ($row = $data->fetch()) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($row['conteudo']); //Faz o parse do HTML no php

    //Junta imagens de postagens diferentes no mesmo array
    $todas_imagens = array_merge($todas_imagens, pegar_imagens($doc));
}

//Remove imagens repetidas
$todas_imagens = array_unique($todas_imagens);

//Pega todas imagens da pasta no seu servidor
foreach (glob('upload/*.{jpg,png,gif,webp}', GLOB_BRACE) as $imagem)
{
      //Verifica se a imagem da pasta NÃO está em nenhuma postagem
      if (!in_array(basename($imagem), $todas_imagens)) {
           //Acaso não estiver deleta a imagem
           unlink($imagem);
      }
}
```

Vale lembrar que se muitos usuários estão editando postagens isto pode causar conflitos, a maneira que creio que ajudaria a amenizar, se realmente tiver mais de um usuário usando o sistema é separar as imagens para cada usuário, poderia separar por pastas, então o `glob()` deverá ser executado somente na pasta que pertence ao usuário especifico.

Outra maneira seria executar o script acima em um CRON (sem a parte do insert e update, já que é algo totalmente separado), isto claro, deverá ser feito em um horário ocioso, em um momento que de preferência ninguém esteja usando o editor, isto você poderia checar através do seu sistema de logins (se ele foi bem trabalhado) ou então definir um horário do qual o sistema entre em modo de manutenção e impeça o acesso somente ao editor de textos, então você agendaria o CRON para executar todo dia neste horário X, poderia até colocar a "limpeza" para um domingo, exemplo:

```
0 03 * * * /var/www/tarefas/limpar-imagens-em-desuso.php
```